# Auto user provisioning with asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip

Is there a way to save users voicemail and numbers in `voicemail.conf` and `extensions.conf` via SMS? For example user send empty sms to number and that will create him record in voicemail and extensions.

What if there are 100+ / 500+ numbers.. I think isn't good idea to save all in single file.

Is there any API or script to do so?

Comment: You can use Twilio API to handle the SMS part. Lets say you send SMS, your Twilio App receives the SMS and perform an action, in this case read SMS body and create an extension and VM.

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. Please make an attempt to do this, and come back with any problems you encounter. Overly broad questions lead to overly broad answers, like the one below, that don't help anyone out and add no value for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use asterisk realtime architecture(configs in database) to store your voicemail and extensions.conf

After that you can create simple script which will do changes based on sms api of any choosed provider.

You also can try use ARI interface for that, but that is more complex.